# how to send an activation code to the user in create user wizard?

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to verify the user who is registering on My Website(using Create User Wizard ) by sending them a code on their E-Mail ID given at registration time...and they will have to use that code to activate his account.
could u please help me with this
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article that walks through doing something very similarl.  The only difference I see between the way they did it and what you are doing is that they included the code in a URL that the user just clicks and you want to have them type it in a box.

Link: http://www.aspcode.net/Requiring-email-verification-for-new-accounts.aspx

or https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153319/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062508-1.aspx